# Do bows do double damage when they break?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In BotW and TotK, an attack with a  melee weapon that causes said weapon to break will do twice as much damage as a normal attack. Does this rule also hold true for bow attacks? Just to be clear, I want an answer that reflects personal testing, not a simple "The wiki doesn't specifically say that this thing works, so it must not work."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently no. I've watched several videos about damage buff exploits and nobody mentions this buff.

Moreover, [Zelda wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon#Breath_of_the_Wild) states:

> Weapons have a set amount of durability and will break when this value reaches zero, dealing twice as much damage as they do so.

This is only present on melee weapons description, bows description only mentions the durability.

---

I can confirm, after testing on a black Moblin, that a brand new bow and a badly damaged one, both with a fully charged arrow, deal the same damage.
This is probably due to the fact that melee weapons actually break on contact with an enemy, bows don't because what hits the target is the arrow.

Comment: "Today" was four days ago.

Comment: Omg sorry. I did and I totally forgot to update the answer, my bad...